# Are collections Mutable?

Tags: c#, collections

In the below example the changes made in the `List B` directly reflect int the `List A`.

```
   List<string> A = new List<string>();
   A.Add("1");
   List<string> B = new List<string>();
   B = A;
   foreach (string value in B)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("B= " + value);
   }
   B.Add("2");
   foreach (string value in A)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("A= " + value);
   }
```

the Output is

> B=1
>
> A=1
>
> A=2

Also the output is the same even if I use an `Arraylist` .

In case of a string the behavior is otherwise!

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = s1;
s2 += "TEST";
Console.WriteLine("S1=" + s1 + "    S2=" + s2);
```

the Output is

> S1=abc     S2=abcTEST

Comment: You can't compare a list with a string, that's comparing apples to oranges. `List.Add` and `String +=` are doing two different things. The former adds a new item to an existing list, the latter creates a new string which will replace the old string.

Comment: @psylogic You may also want to read up on string interning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

Collections are mutable. Strings are immutable. So in the beginning `A` and `B` are references to two different lists. When you do `B = A` both `B` and `A` reference the same list in memory so changes to one reflect in the other.

Strings however are immutable, so the `+=` operator actually returns a new string. So in the beginning you actually have the same case here, `s1` and `s2` points to the same string in memory, but `s2 += "TEST"` will cause a new string to be allocated and `s2` will be a reference to that one instead.

Comment: You would get the same behaviour as with the string, if you would do: `B = new List<string>(B); B.Add("2");`

Answer (score 4):

You're absolutely wrong: you're just setting `ListA` referenced object into `ListB` reference. That is, now `ListB` is `ListA`. Thus, you're always modifying `ListA`.

Obviously collections are mutable unless you use [immutable collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable(v=vs.111).aspx) or [read-only collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You have answered your own question with your code examples. Unless you use an [immutable collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769092%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), then collections are mutable. Change the list referred to by both `A` and `B` and the list itself changes, rather than a new list being created.

Strings are immutable though. So `s2 += "TEST";` creates a new string, which is assigned to `s2`. At that point, `s1` and `s2` refer to different strings.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below sample:-

[image]

Here, the output will be:

**abc**

**123abc**

Now, uncomment the commented line **s1 = "XXX"** and run the code.
Now, the output will be:

**XXX**

**123abc**

Observe here that even after changing the value of s1 the result of s2 did not change. It depicts that a s1 is not referring to the same object as that of s2. Or in other words when we declared **s2 += s1**, a new string gets created. **Therefore, we can say that String is Immutable.**

Now, take a look over the below sample with collections:

[image]

The output will be:

**L2 : a**

Now, uncomment the commented line of code from the sample and see the output.

The output will be:

**L2 : a**

**L2 : c**

This depicts that l1 and l2 are referencing to the same object now which means that no new object has been created unlike in case of string. **Therefore, collections are Mutable.**